# Trouble to get specific language in each field

Tags: php, request, repeat, words

I try to create my form to add category in 3 languages:  "fr", "en", "es".

When I work with 2 languages everything is good, but when I put a third language "es", it doesn’t work.

This is my request

```
<?php
$catid=  $_GET["cat"];
$Command = "SELECT t.cat,t.cat_id, fr.cat as cat_fr,es.cat as cat_es
FROM category t 
INNER JOIN categoty_translation fr on t.cat_id = fr.catId
INNER JOIN category_translation es on t.cat_id =es.catId
INNER JOIN language l ON fr.langcode = l.code and es.langcode = l.code
WHERE t.cat_id='$catid'"; 
$cat = $row["cat"];
$cat_fr = $row["cat_fr"];
$cat_es= $row["cat_es"];
?>
```

In the form, I get the Spanish word two times
This the form:

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label for="cat en" class="control-label">English Category </label>
<input type="text" name="cat" id="cat" value="<?=$cat?>" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="cat fr" class="control-label">French Category </label>
<input type="text" name="cat_fr" value="<?=$cat_fr?>" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="cat es" class="control-label">Spanish Category</label>
<input type="text" name="cat_es" value="<?=$cat_es?>" class="form-control">
</div>
```

In my database.  i have 2 tables: "category" that content default language (en) and category translation that content tree language "en", "fr" and "es".

Like I said if I use 2 languages everything is okay, but when I add the third language I got only the default language and only the last language "es" in the file input fr and es.

Comment: Could you give us an html example of how exactly it looks like? I cant exactly tell what the problem here is by looking at your code.

Comment: @dheerajVadlani i don't think it's a problem vo mysqli_set_charset

Comment: @SimonBalling it's hard to hard a html exemple, i must enter all code php mysqli

Comment: @timmo when use characters whose unicode is greater than 1 byte you must specify the charset...

Comment: @dheerajVadlani mysqli_set_charset() its already in my mysql connection.

Comment: @timmo make sure that the language you are using is supported by charset that you are using in mysqli_set_charset() and also in the html page use the same charset in meta tag.

Comment: @dheerajVadlani my code work perfectly for 2 languages.  I got trouble when i a the spanish language.  It seem that i dont care of english language, like the default language is in category table.

Comment: @timmo what is the exact output you got with spanish language..

Comment: go through this link http://kunststube.net/frontback/

Comment: @dheerajVadlani in my input field french I got spanish word.  in my spanish word i got spanish word

Comment: The problem if is my sql select

Comment: Yes problem with ur mysql select...